# Issue With Compiling My App

Tags: hadoop

I have written a short java app for Hadoop platform. It is a pretty simple app in which I am using a class called Word. Word is defined in a separated file and it is supposed to be a data type. Eclipse does not issue any error. When I try to compile using this:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main MyApp.java
```

I get the following error:

> MyApp.java:18: error: cannot find symbol  public static class
>   TokenizerMapper extends Mapper {

(The arrow is pointing to Word)

Comment: you'd better post the whole piece of code. it seems you didn't include hadoop class path when you're compiling

Comment: The error is not with Hadoop. If I use other data types (e.g. IntWritable) it works just fine. But when create a custom type I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the source folder as a sourcepath:
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main -sourcepath ./ MyApp.java